# How to pass struct into smart contract in Etherscan

Tags: solidity, etherscan

**How to correctly pass struc into the smart contract in Etherscan?**
I have a problem with a smart contract function that accepts struct as parameters on  Etherscan.

**Here are the structures.**

[image]

**Here is a read function that accepts orderParameters struct and returns the order hash. Tuple that is passed to the function**

```
["0x6DAFBD4fe90dC0c770BDe01c2521Fc8F92d0358b",["0x1BcB64dD1055d86153E2c6d333E44674344D5527","0x932Ca55B9Ef0b3094E8Fa82435b3b4c50d713043",1115,1],["0x1BcB64dD1055d86153E2c6d333E44674344D5527","0xb35CC02a14315fc5fb8bE02933321aaA4b8F7Fcc",0,11000],0,1641377878,1704449878,1688548678,[["0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",2000]],0]
```

[image]

**On the other hand, I have a write function to fulfil this order with similar input parameters but Etherscan returns an error while accepting the same parameters.**

[image]

Comment: IMO, you should add more context (e.g. the function ABI + the related struct definition)